# How can I access to a view programmatically that declare invisible in xml?

Tags: java, android, android-view

I have a layout like this, main_layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<RelativeLayout 
            android:id="@+id/testLayout"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="64dp"
            >
            <ImageButton 
                android:layout_width="32dp"
                android:layout_height="32dp"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"/>
            <ImageButton 
                android:layout_width="32dp"
                android:layout_height="32dp"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
                android:visibility="invisible"/>
</RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Now I want to acces the second button in java code, so this is the code section that cause NullPointerException:

```
RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.testLayout);
ImageButton b = (ImageButton) rl.getChildAt(1);
```

I have found a new interesting point.this code shows that rl has only one child in code section, so rl does not have the second button at all.why is that?

```
 log.d("child Counter", String.valueOf(rl.getChildCount()));
```

this shows 1 in LogCat

And this is the onCreate method for those who think this is the cause of the problem, but I know this is not.

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_layout);
}
```

Comment: instead of gechild you can assign the id to the imagebutton, then access with the id

Comment: @manivannan - I think maybe he knows that, as he has already retrieved his RelativeLayout that way. Could you clarify Babak-Na?

Comment: Are you using same layout file for setContentView?

Comment: I know the simple way of ID to find the view.But I want to manage the views of the testLayout as a list.So I want to use index of the view instead of ID.

Comment: I have found a new interesting point.this code shows that rl has only one child in code section, so rl does not have the second button at all.why is that?
log.d("child Counter", String.valueOf(rl.getChildCount()));
this shows 1 in LogCat

Comment: @Babak-Na - Can we see some more of your onCreate method including the call to setContentView, and the name of the layout file? Because I can't think of any other reason this wouldn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Your code is working perfectly,try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/testLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="64dp">
    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"/>
    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
        android:visibility="invisible"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.testLayout);
        ImageButton b1 = (ImageButton) rl.getChildAt(0);
        b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Image Button 1 clicked",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        ImageButton b2 = (ImageButton) rl.getChildAt(1);
        b2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        b2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Image Button 2 clicked",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Step 1: Declare an id for the Second button as shown below and access it.

```
<RelativeLayout 
            android:id="@+id/testLayout"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="64dp"
            >
            <ImageButton 
                android:layout_width="32dp"
                android:layout_height="32dp"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"/>
            <ImageButton 
                android:id="@+id/imgButton2"
                android:layout_width="32dp"
                android:layout_height="32dp"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
                android:visibility="invisible"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

and access it in java file

```
ImageButton b = (ImageButton)  findViewById(R.id.imgButton2);
```

Step 2: If you want to use getChild , please determine the whether you are able to retrive all the childs , In your case the Relative Layout has two child , this is can be achiveable using get `rl.getChildCount();`  and getChild and assign it to view as shown below.

```
for(int i=0;i<r1.getChildCount();i++){
       View child=relativeLayout.getChildAt(i);
       //your processing code....
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, But I know this solution.The question is why the second button is not as the second child in testLayout

Comment: @Babak-Na: can you please post your stack trace from logcat and also please conform are you using setContentView or addView to make sure that your setting the layout to the view?

Answer (score 2):

you might want to add an id for every widget

```
<RelativeLayout 
            android:id="@+id/testLayout"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="64dp"
            >
            <ImageButton 
            android:id="@+id/imageview1"
                android:layout_width="32dp"
                android:layout_height="32dp"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"/>
            <ImageButton 
            android:id="@+id/imageview2"
                android:layout_width="32dp"
                android:layout_height="32dp"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
                android:visibility="invisible"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

and access it with

```
ImageButton b = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageview1);
```

then you can make it visible by

```
b.setVisiblity(View.VISIBLE);
```

Comment: Forget about add an id, this is not the answer that I am searching.